# perforce map depot as local drive

Tags: perforce

How do I map files in a depot as a local drive.
Basically I want to be able to browse the files in the depot using cygwin, just like I do it for a local drive.
I tried several options but none of them worked.

- Map the path \sw\src... as a Mapped Network drive in windows. But as expected this doesnt work since perforce is client-serve based.
- I can browse using URL `http://p4viewer/get//sw/src` in a webbrowser.
  But I cant open it in cygwin. Is there any tool that allows to map a
  URL as a local drive ?

Comment: You can't directly map the server drive. But you might try something like P4EXP: http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-plugin-windows-explorer

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just create a local work space?  Then the files would be on your local drive and you could treat them as any other file on your workstation.

Comment: Make sure if you edit those files on the local files system that you do not accidentally submit the changes.  Perforce keeps track of changes made outside the GUI/Command line as well...

Comment: The depot is huge 500GB and it is shared by a large corporation so syncing the whole thing is not practical.
But sometimes I will need to browse files in other branches/path. I know I can do it using P4V thats what I do now, but it would be more convenient if I can map it as a drive and using command line.

Comment: Can't say that have a solution for that other than working it as a workspace but in sections.